# "Reply to sender" rule only running once per sender per day?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have an Outlook 2007 rule set up to reply to sender with a custom reply template if the subject or body contains specific text.  This rule works the first time for a specific sender, but doesn't work if the sender sends me another email in the same day.  I even confirmed this by setting my PC clock ahead by a day.  Sure enough, the auto reply was sent successfully.  This tells me that there is something in Outlook that's specifically keeping auto-replies from going out in the same day to the same sender.

I am aware that perhaps this is a preventative measure to keep two machines from entering a feedback loop with one another, but I want to circumvent whatever is causing this so that my rule works unconditionally every time even if it's 100 times a day.

**Update:**  I've discovered that it's not only per day, but per running instance of Outlook.  This means you can have your rule send out an automatic reply, shut down/restart Outlook, and have it send out another auto reply.  If it's in the same instance, though, it won't work.  There has to be a way around this.  Maybe the answer lies in VBA, an option I am about to explore.

Comment: if you found the answer, you should rewrite the question and post the answer.  Thats what this site is for. :)

Comment: if you've found an answer, post it as an answer. I don't understand why you have to delete it without sharing the answer

Comment: Is this an Exchange account?

Comment: @Sathya: SE allows users to delete their own questions. The only reason I can't now is because I added bounty. If I had just researched a few hours longer before doing so, I would have been able to delete this question and you wouldn't have had a word to say about it. At any rate, I didn't **really** find an objective answer, just hints that it can't circumvented. I've decided to write a VBA macro that does this, but, by the time I get around to it, bounty will have already been systematically awarded to a random, lucky answerer, thus resulting in a misleading Q&A which is bad for SE.

Comment: In that case, I removed the bounty. You should be able to delete your question if you strongly feel about it. Other than that I don't think there's any harm from keeping it around, even if there's no answer (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.  My research has pointed me to the fact that this, as I said in my question, is a preventative measure implemented by Microsoft to keep two senders from entering to a spam feedback loop.  The only way I know that this can be done is by writing a VBA macro.  I have started writing it, but I will not have the time to finish it in this week or next.  If I ever do finish it, I will come back here and post it.  For now, since the bounty clock is ticking, I am just going to answer this now to close out the issue.

Comment: Nitpick: it's not simply implemented by Microsoft it's written into the standards RFCs that govern the transmission of email, and to which all mail clients and MTAs should adhere.

Comment: So auto-replying to an email I receive is against these "standards"?  I wouldn't mind seeing some official literature on this.

Comment: It's in [RFC3834](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3834). Enjoy being bored to tears. It basically boils down to: don't autorespond to an autoresponder, don't autorespond more often than X, and set proper headers to indicate that it is an automated response. Not adhering to these recommendations is a quick way to kill a mail server due to autorespond loops.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you don't have a compatibility issue that might be a result of a rule that was "inherited" from a previous version of Office.

Please verify the following:

1. In **Tools** → **Rules and Alerts**, in the **E-mail Rules** tab press **Options** button (should be the rightmost option)
2. In the Options window click the **Upgrade Now**. Although this is considered to be a performance only I think you should try it.

If this has any relevance to your issue or has some beneficial effects please report back.

Comment: My Upgrade Now button is disabled, so I can't click it.

Comment: OK, that rules out the compatibility issue.